# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load echoprint-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, android-ndk, metaio, codegen

I am using [Echoprint](https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid) in my android project as explained [here](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/) and it works ok. However, when I try to add the [metaioSDK](https://metaio.app.boxenterprise.net/SDK-PC) library to the project (just add it, not even use it), I can't run Echoprint anymore. I get:

```
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-92046    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load echoprint-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.kkt-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.kkt-1]: findLibrary returned null    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at edu.gvsu.masl.echoprint.Codegen.<clinit>(Codegen.java:44)    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at edu.gvsu.masl.echoprint.AudioFingerprinter.run(AudioFingerprinter.java:199)    
07-17 14:20:34.194: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The file `libechoprint-jni.so` is in the "/libs/armeabi/" folder and I call it `System.loadLibrary("echoprint-jni")`, which worked before adding the metaio library. How come it doesn't work after? Ask if any other details are needed/printscreens/etc.

**EDIT:**

I've noticed that EchoprintLibrary has `libechoprint-jni.so` in: `/libs/armeabi/`

metaioSDK has about 7 .so files in: `/libs/armeabi-v7a/`

On my phone, when the app only uses Echoprint, I can find the `libechoprint-jni.so` in

```
/data/data/com.example/kkt/lib/
/data/app-lib/com.example.kkt-2/
```

When I also add metaioSDK to the mix, `libechoprint-jni.so` is nowhere to be found, but all the metaio .so files can be found in

```
/data/data/com.example/kkt/lib/
/data/app-lib/com.example.kkt-1/
```

So I guess in the end, it may be a question of how to have .so libraries from multiple sources..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by moving the Echoprint source files inside my own project and moving the libechoprint-jni.so in the metaio libs/armeabi-v7a folder, next to the other .so files. Basically all the .so files had to be grouped under one folder/project. Might not work for everyone, but it worked for me.